# Establish optional sampling theorem for right-continuous submartingale {$X_t,{F_t} ; 0 \leq t<\infty $} and optional times $S\leq T$ under conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> Establish the optional sampling theorem for a right-continuous submartingale $ \left\{X_t,\mathscr{F_t} ; 0 \leq t < \infty \right\}$ and optional times $S\leq T$ under either of the following two conditions:
>
> **i.** $T$ is a *bounded* optional time (there exists a number $a>0$, such that $T \leq a$);
> **ii.** $\exists$ an integrable random variable $Y$, such that $X_t \leq E(Y|\mathscr{F_t})$ a. s. $P$, for every $t \geq 0$.
>
> [Problem `3.23`, Page `20`, Chapter `1` of [Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus By Ioannis Karatzas and Steven Shreve](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Brownian_Motion_and_Stochastic_Calculus/w0SgBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)   ]

I am trying to solve part (ii) of the problem.

The Theorem before the Problem was

[image]

My first idea was to consider the process
$
\hat{X}_t
=\begin{cases}
X_t,& \text{ if } t < \infty\\
\mathbf{E}[Y \mid { \mathscr{F}_\infty }] & \text{if else.}
\end{cases}.$

And use the above Theorem, but then my problem is to recover the original process in the event $[S=\infty]$. Should I consider something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give in the following a sketch of a direct argument.

The idea is stolen (shamelessly) from [George Lowther's blog](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/optional-sampling/), in which the proof of Optional Sampling Theorem is based on the following reduction of the problem.

First the assertion of the theorem is true (please take a look at argument of GL's blog) if you can prove the following claim  for a sub-martingale process $X$  : 
$$E[X_\tau - X_\sigma]\geq 0~ (Eq.1)$$

To show this introduce (within the scope of hypotheses i or ii) the following sequence of simple (in the sense of GL's blog) stopping times :
$$\tau_n = min \{m/n ; m, n\in \mathbb{N}^2 \}$$ (and $\sigma_n$ along the same line), observe (show) that both sequence are well defined and converge almost surely to $\tau, \sigma$.

Now you can conclude if you can show that $X_{\tau_n},X_{\sigma_n}$ are both Uniformly Integrable (UI), because for them it is easy to see that :

$$E[X_{\tau_n} - X_{\sigma_n}]\geq 0~ (Eq.1_n)$$

Using $L^1$ convergence of U. I. sequence, then you are done because this implies (1).

GL's entry of the proof for the UI property of $X_{\tau_n}$ is done through [lemma 6](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/cadlag-modifications/#scn_cadlag_lem6), but for it to be meaningful $X_{\tau_n}$ has to exist which is the point to prove especially for the item i- where $\tau$ and/or $\sigma$ can be infinite with positive probability and so $\tau_n$ and/or $\sigma_n$.